# Python, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'

Tags: python

Currently I'm trying to copy a picture that is half on python and make it symmetrical. Where the picture contains half of the overall pixel number. 
On the left side is the original. And I want to copy those pixels from left to right and make the entire picture symmetrical

The original picture would look like this:

```
a a b b - - - -

a b c d - - - -

a b a b - - - -
```

And the output picture would be:

```
a a b b b b a a

a b c d d c b a

a b a b b a b a
```

And the code im working on is as follows:

```
from csmedia import *

def symmetry(img):
    output_image = None

     w, h = img.size()
     for y in range(h):
         for x in range(w):
         os = img.get(x, y)
         img.set(w - x - 1, y, os)
     return output_image

if __ name__ == __main__:
     img = load_picture('img/half_star.png')
     image = symmetry(img)
     image.show
```

However when I run the code it gives me "AttributeError: 'NoneType' objects has no attribute 'show'"

I hope the question was clear enough.
Thank you.

Comment: Your `output_image` in the `symmetry` function is set to `None` which is what you return from it so the moment you try to reference show on it (`image.show`) it will prompt the `AttributeError` as `None` indeed doesn't have a `show` method/property.

Comment: I maybe can't see this on the phone, but where do you set the copied image to be the output image / when do you set output_image?

Comment: symmetry() returns `output_image`, which is set to `None` and never changed, so symmetry() always returns `None`.  Perhaps you meant to return `img` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `symmetry` function is not building an output image, but modifying the original image. You could modify it like this:

```
def symmetry(img):
    w, h = img.size()

    output_image = Image(width=2*w, height=h)  # Or whatever method your library provides to create an empty image object

    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(w):
            original_pixel = img.get(x, y)
            output_image.set(x, y, original_pixel)  # Copying original image
            output_image.set(w - x - 1, y, original_pixel)  # mirroring original image

    return output_image
```

Notice that if you're using OpenCV (the most used library for image processing), python's for loops aren't the best tool to do the job. You could use `numpy.flip` and merge together the original and flipped arrays to get a boost in the speed of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you just wanted to do:

```
output_image.set(w - x - 1, y, os)
```

instead of

```
img.set(w - x - 1, y, os)
```